# Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script Content Security Policy directive:default-src self

Tags: javascript, http-headers

In my application, I want Content Security Policy: all directives should be set to self, but when I am trying to do that it is showing the following error

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self';".

```
at Function (<anonymous>)
at Function._init (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:8:3195)
at yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:9:4331
at yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:9:4558
```

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-BfUVqxUMiFIZGvtAvlU3O1tTN9idUT5IuAIpMSM2F5g='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

> Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i&display=swap' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content security policy must have this directive:

```
default-src 'self';
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; 
style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;
```

and more.

Comment: Hi, 'unsafe-eval' and 'unsafe-inline' should not be included in CSP.

Comment: It is OK if you understand the risks, its a trade-of, if you can't change your application. You simply either add it or rewrite your application so it doesn't break your policy. So, the question is then , what is your question?

Comment: I am using Moodle in which by default yui-combo.php is already present. During VAPT (security testing)  it was observed that below mentioned HTTP Headers were not set: 1. Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains
2. X-Frame-Options, Frame-Options X-Frame-Options: deny
3. X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
4. X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
5. Content Security Policy: all directives should be set to self
'unsafe-eval' and 'unsafe-inline' should not be included in CSP.
All four are done but for 5th point i am getting this errors.

Comment: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-MjSZjCpAdx/Z4gQYwAJ4KyuBAV2cUMjgsTJ4917lHOA='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined

Comment: But what is your actual question?

Comment: My question is that http headers should set to self. In moodle whenever we download installer all this yui-combo.php and font.google.api are already present in it. Now my application goes for security testing that team said me Content Security Policy: all directives should be set to self 'unsafe-eval' and 'unsafe-inline' should not be included in CSP. But when i tried to put this in my apache configuration (defaultp-src 'self') i am getting above errors as shown.

Comment: To comply with a policy that only allows default-src 'self', then you need to rewrite your pages and HTML so that it only loads resources from your own site and not any external requests like fonts.googleapis.com.  But in reality, most sites using CSP will allow some domains like fonts.googleapis.com, as a compromise. It is a trade-of between security, what is practical and cost to rewrite your application/site to comply with the policy...

Comment: @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i&display=swap');
Url is imported in css file can you help in this to keep self.

Comment: Download and add the file locally to your site: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i&display=swap' or accept and trust fonts.googleapis.com?

Comment: @SunnyAdhatrao If your team forbids you to use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and inline listeners, then re-write your code so that it doesn't use those concepts.

Comment: unsafe-eval defeats the purpose of Content Security Policy. the given scripts should be allowed using nonce, srcipt-src 'self' and external script sources included as well

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **helmet** on your Node.JS server, you can configure the following:

```
server.use(helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: false
}));
```

Or you can configure the following to whitelist a specific domain:

```
server.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      "script-src": ["'self'", "example.com"],
      "style-src": null,
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

## `unsafe-eval` basically nullifies the protections you would gain from Content-Security-Policy.

The whole point of Content-Security-Policy is to protect your app from possible Javascript Injections and Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS) attacks.

You set

`Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self';`

to only execute safe scripts that are served as files from your own origin - the same source the app is hosted.

Now, if you allow `unsafe-eval`, then that `eval` becomes a point of entry for the attacker, and once they manage to inject their javascript into your app, they have total control and all other benefits you'd get from CSP are voided.

So if you want to have CSP enabled (in a way that makes sense), having `eval` in your code makes it lose that sense.

Therefore, if you're serious about using CSP to protect your app, you should focus on eliminating your need for `eval` instead on allowing `unsafe-eval` within the CSP.

See this Google research paper on CSP for details:

[CSP Is Dead, Long Live CSP! On the Insecurity of
Whitelists and the Future of Content Security Policy](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45542.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

## I got the same error when I tried to create a Chrome extension.

Anyway, let me tell you why this error occurred.

**Here is some point.**

- The error message indicates that the CSP does not allow the use of `'unsafe-eval'` as a source of the script.
- However, this means that you cannot use the `eval()` method/function in your extension code.

**So now, let's see how we can fix this issue..!**
We can modify the CSP of your extension to allow `'unsafe-eval'`. To do this, we need to add the following line to our `manifest.json` file.

In the below section. If you are using `manifest V2` then use this line.

```json
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

Or If you are using `manifest V3` then you have to use this line.

```json
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
  }
```

Comment: ...and, in MV3, you'll get this error: 'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "'unsafe-eval'" in directive 'script-src' and the extension is not loaded. Wrong way, sorry.

Comment: Wrong v3 answer, after implementing your answer, i am facing following error:

'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "'unsafe-eval'" in directive 'script-src'.

And extension is also not being loaded

Comment: It's not allowed in manifest V3, you should update your answer