# « unsafe-eval » error when I’m trying to import Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, stripe-payments, unsafe-eval

I can’t fix this issue :

`Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'`

I am using a server Node.js which is hosted on Heroku and i have this issue only on Chrome. It happened when i tried to add Stripe to my website and i have already add every URL Stripe need in my CSP.

I tried to change my CSP and add « unsafe-eval » in my script-src but i still have the same problem.

```
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
directives: {
  defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
  connectSrc: ["'self'", "https://checkout.stripe.com","https://api.stripe.com", "https://maps.googleapis.com", "https://api.alternative.me/fng/"], // Allows connections to Stripe Checkout
  defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
  scriptSrc: ["'self'","https://checkout.stripe.com","https://js.stripe.com", "https://maps.googleapis.com", "https://connect-js.stripe.com", "'unsafe-eval'"],
  frameSrc: ["'self'", "https://checkout.stripe.com", "https://js.stripe.com/","https://hooks.stripe.com","https://connect-js.stripe.com"], // Allows frames from Stripe Checkout
  imgSrc: ["'self'", "https://*.stripe.com", "data:"], // Allows images from Stripe
  baseUri: ["'self'"],
  objectSrc: ["'none'"],
  upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
},
```

}));

Network response header:

Content-Security-Policy

default-src 'self';connect-src 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com https://api.stripe.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://api.alternative.me/fng/;script-src 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://connect-js.stripe.com 'unsafe-eval';frame-src 'self' …

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script Content Security Policy directive:default-src self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72376413/refused-to-evaluate-a-string-as-javascript-because-unsafe-eval-is-not-an-allow)

Comment: Could you please share the full CSP config that you're using?

Comment: I see `defaultSrc` is repeated, maybe it's causing the issue?

Comment: @vanya no… i still have the same issue

Comment: Are you sure this is the config that's actually applied in the browser?

Comment: @vanya yes you can see it on my CSP in my Network response headers that i just added